# mutating method sent to immutable object with userInfo (null)

Tags: ios5, core-data

I want to clear all the data by fetch all records and delete them one by one:

```
- (void) clear{
    for (Program *program in [self getAllProgram]){
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:program];
    }        
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem deleting program: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

- (NSArray *)getAllProgram{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Program"inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"freq = %@", self.freq];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    // Order the events by creation date, most recent first.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sid" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    return [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

}
```

The error is

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. 
>   -[__NSCFSet removeAllObjects]: mutating method sent to immutable object with userInfo (null)

Who can tell me the reason or tell me the one good practice ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a fetched results controller somewhere. Set that controller's `delegate` to `nil` during the delete. I usually actually set the whole FRC to `nil` and update my whole data display after a large data change.

If that is not feasible, handle this case in the notification handler, like

```
if (!userInfo) return;
```

Comment: Sorry , I did not use NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: You can still handle it in the callback as indicated.